# Which file keeps the state of brew?

Tags: homebrew

I see this when I run homebrew. Which file in homebrew keep the information on when the last cleanup was run? Thanks.

```
==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now...
```

Comment: This isn't on-topic for SO, maybe should migrate to SuperUser. Anyway, `man brew` and `brew config -v` give you a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew writes a [`.cleaned` file](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/b6dc6a0e52e6166afa25be505656cd0dd50c9211/Library/Homebrew/cleanup.rb#L124) in its cache directory when you run `brew cleanup`. It then checks the file’s creation date to know if it’s time for some cleanup. You can get the location of your Homebrew cache directory with the following command:

```
brew --cache
```

Note you can also tell Homebrew not to run `brew cleanup` for you by setting the `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP` environment variable.